# How to convert RGB values to physical radiometry and/or photometry quantities and back?

Tags: visible-light, computer

What are RGB values actually mean in physical sense?

Are these values mean some amount of light or energy per surface unit or what?

Are they logarithmic?

Fro example, why do these values are limited to 255? Is this technical limitation or the expression of the nature of some physical quantity?

Suppose I would like to have maximally physical image format. Which quantities should I store in the pixel?

How to convert RGB values to any sort of physical quantities and vise versa?

**UPDATE**

I noticed, that one of characteristics of LCD displays is their luminance, measured in candelas per square meters. For example, typical monitors has 250-300 cd/m^2.

Since this quantity is per surface unit, it does not depend on the surface of monitor. I.e. large monitors with greater numbers of same pixels will have the same luminance.

Ergo, the luminance is that quantity I was searching for.

If pixel has value of 255:255:255, then it has nominal luminance, i.e. 300 cd/m^2 for monitor with that characteristic.

Still thinking on values of RGB components.

Comment: Possible duplicate Phys.SE questions about RGB: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+rgb

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1472514/2071794.

Answer (score 1):

To display colors on monitors, programs needed some way to define the color. Since most monitors (at the time) were CRTs with RGB guns, the easiest method was to specify the intensity of the RGB guns. Each gun was given a byte (255 levels) of intensity, although I believe that the hardware could not resolve the smallest changes. So instead of 256 levels of red, there was about 100.

Since every CRT varies in the amount of color produced, it would be impossible to equate an RGB value with a particular color on the screen; although you should have the same color on the printer.

> What do the RGB values actually mean in physical sense?

It represents a color combination of red, green and blue.

> Do these values mean some amount of light or energy per surface unit or what?

It represents the amount of red, green and blue to use in a specified value.

> Are they logarithmic?

No.

> For example, why do these values are limited to 255? Is this technical limitation or the expression of the nature of some physical quantity?

It is a technical limitation in the programs and a physical limitation in the hardware. The value was limited to 1 byte (255 values), but the hardware was not adequate to resolve the smallest changes. If modern monitors are capable of displaying all 255 values, your eyes may not be able to perceive all the changes.

> Suppose I would like to have maximally physical image format. Which quantities should I store in the pixel?

I don't know what you mean.

> How to convert RGB values to any sort of physical quantities and vise versa?

If you print out the color for the RGB value, you should have the same color every time (even from different printers). You could then match the color to the color standards (such as Pantone).

Comment: A few nitpicks... All modern displays and printers use sRGB, which is gamma-corrected. So you're correct that it's not logarithmic. But it's not linear either. Also, plenty of hardware can provide more accurate colors than 255-255-255, even though not all programs take advantage. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth

Comment: @SteveB Yes, I agree that modern displays and printers are capable of greater color definition, but when the RGB values were created, the displays were mainly CRTs which wouldn't have the capability of displaying all 255 levels. But I did read somewhere that the eye was unable to differentiate minor changes (which is why JPEG compression works so well).

Answer (score 0):

Working out wavelength is a bit tricky, and not always possible (another example is the color obtained by mixing equal amounts of red and blue light. That purple has no single wavelength).

But if all you want to do is identify the colour by name, then the HSV model would be a good one to use. HSV is Hue (where the colour is around the colour wheel), Saturation (how much colour there is as opposed to being a shade of black/grey/white) and Value (how bright or dark the pixel is). In this case Hue is probably exactly what you want.

If you are using a .NET language, then you're in luck. See the Color.GetHue Method which does all the work for you.

Otherwise, see HSV at Wikipedia for more details.

In essence, if you have R, G and B as floats ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 (instead of ints from 0 to 255 for example), then:

M = max(R, G, B)
m = min(R, G, B)
C = M-m

if M = m then H' is undefined (The pixel is some shade of grey)
if M = R then H' = (G-B)/C mod 6
if M = G then H' = (B-R)/C + 2
if M = B then H' = (R-G)/C + 4

When converting RGB to HSV you then multiply H' by 60 degrees, but for your purposes H' is probably fine. It will be a float ranging from 0 to 6 (almost). 0 is Red (as is 6). 1 is Yellow, with values between 0 and 1 being shaded between Red and Yellow. So 0.5 would be Orange. The important landmarks are:

0 - Red
1 - Yellow
2 - Green
3 - Cyan
4 - Blue
5 - Purple
6 - Red (again)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a different tack on this question.

The use of RGB in computer monitors and other color display systems is entirely determined by human biology, not physics. The subpixel values of R, G, and B represent the amount of activation induced in a human's cone retinal cells. Monochromatic yellow light (about 570 nm wavelength) creates signals in both the red and green cones of our eyes. So, to produce yellow color, computer displays light up red and green subpixels to stimulate the right cones in our eyes by the right amount.

If humans had four cone cells like birds, then our displays would have four colors: RGBU (red, green, blue, ultraviolet), for example, or IRGB (infrared, red, green blue).

If you wanted to have a maximally physical image format, you would record the current/voltage induced in each rod (for brightness) and cone (for color) cell in the eye that was looking at the image (assuming the eye didn't have any defects like red-green colorblindness (like mine)). RGB is a pretty reasonable approximation of this scheme.

Comment: Actually the cones have different responses to the same intensity of their maximum frequency. See http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-2/visible-light-and-the-Eye-s-Response

Comment: @LDC3 I'm finding different information here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colcon.html

Comment: Did you noticed what was written below the figure? `The "blue" cones have the highest sensitivity and are mostly found outside the fovea. The shapes of the curves are obtained by measurement of the absorption by the cones, but the relative heights for the three types are set equal for lack of detailed data.` It appears that our brains level out the intensities.